# Pytorch: How to create a custom Dataset with reference table

Tags: python, pytorch, torchvision

I have a reference.csv file that has three columns: Type, Class, and Path. Here are the first 5 example rows:

```
"Type","Class","Path"
"train","A","./path1/001.jpg"
"train","A","./path2/002.jpg"
"test","C","./path3/003.jpg"
"train","B","./path4/001.jpg"
"test","B","./path5/002.jpg"
...
```

In a more viewer friendly format:

```
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|         Type         |       Class      |       Path       |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        train         |         A        | ./path1/001.jpg  |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        train         |         A        | ./path2/002.jpg  |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        train         |         C        | ./path3/003.jpg  |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        test          |         B        | ./path4/001.jpg  |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
|        test          |         B        | ./path5/002.jpg  |
|----------------------|------------------|------------------|
```

I want to create a Dataset class (torch.utils.data.Dataset) to read the images so I can use the DataLoader (torch.utils.data.DataLoader).

What is the correct way to create a custom Dataset using a reference table?

Comment: Kindly look into this https://towardsdatascience.com/building-efficient-custom-datasets-in-pytorch-2563b946fd9f

Comment: I have yet to see this generalized, generic form in a tutorial and I think many can benefit from this common reference.